# Как работают compound literals или внутреннее представление

Tags: c

Вероятно некоторые знают что такое compound literals и умеют использовать это на практике.

Однако у меня возник вопрос по внутреннему представлению этих литералов.

Ну предположим я имею такую запись: `int *a = (int[]){10, 20, 30};` - таким образом я создал и присвоил указателю адрес созданного где-то в памяти массива типа int.

Можно ли предположить что запись: `int *a = (int[]){10, 20, 30};` - эквивалентна следующей записи?

```
int arr[] = {10,20,30};
int *parr = arr;
```

По какой схеме идет присвоение адреса компаунд литерала?

Comment: Что означит "схема присвоения"?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow имеется ввиду как внутри представлен механизм compound literals

Comment: Какой механизм? Неизвестно, как создаются массивы? В чем проблема?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow ну вы внизу вроде как описали это

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Да, можно так считать. Аналогия из двух объявлений вами составлена корректно.

Время жизни compound literal в точности определяется тем декларативным регионом, в котором он указан и совпадает с временем жизни обычной переменной того же типа, объявленной в том же контексте. То есть compound literal - это просто аналог безымянной переменной соответствующего типа с соответствующим инициализатором.

---

Однако с этим в языке С связана одна тонкость. До появления compound literals в С не существовало отдельного вопроса времени жизни объектов, объявленных, например, в ветках `if`

```
if (...)
  int a = 5;
else
  int b = 42;
```

Так как объявления в языке С не являются и никогда не являлись statements, такой код является в С некорректным. Чтобы в С создать локальный декларативный регион, допускающий объявление переменных, необходимо явно использовать `{}`. То есть время жизни обычных (именованных) локальных объектов в С всегда очерчено явным блоком `{}` и полностью объясняется через свойства блока.

Однако с появлением в языке compound literals проблема времени жизни возникла вот в такой форме

```
int *a, *b, *c;
if (a = (int []) { 1, 2, 3 })
  b = (int []) { 4, 5, 6 };
else
  c = (int []) { 7, 8, 9 };
```

Каково должно быть время жизни таких compound literals? Должны ли они существовать после `if`?

До сих пор ни сам `if`, ни его ветки в языке С не являлись отдельными декларативными регионами - как сказано выше, в этом не было никакой необходимости. Однако после введения в язык compound literals в С99, было принято решение пойти по пути С++ и локализовать время жизни таких литералов. Теперь в С как сам `if`, так и его ветки, являются *неявными блоками*, ограничивающими время жизни созданных в них compound literals (и область видимости объявленных в них имен, см. ниже).

Т.е. теперь, начиная с С99, вышеприведенный `if` эквивалентен

```
int *a, *b, *c;
{
  if (a = (int []) { 1, 2, 3 })
  {
    b = (int []) { 4, 5, 6 };
  }
  else
  {
    c = (int []) { 7, 8, 9 };
  }
}
```

со всеми вытекающими, т.е. с "повисшими" значениями указателей. Эта же модификация относится и к другим видам statements.

Это, кстати, привело к потере обратной совместимости с "классическим" С в ряде редко используемых контекстов. Например, в языке С разрешается объявлять новые типы в `sizeof` и в кастах. Пользуясь этой возможностью в С89/90 можно написать такой код

```
int foo(int a)
{
  if (a == sizeof(enum { A }))
    a = sizeof(enum { B });
  else 
    a = sizeof(enum { C });

  return a + A + B + C; /* ОК в С89/90. Ошибка в C99 */
}
```

После С99, из-за введения неявных блоков в `if`, такой код больше не компилируется.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54663/discussion-on-answer-by-ant---compound-literals---).

Answer (score 3):

Составной литерал создает неименованный объект. Его длительность хранения зависит от того, определен он внутри функции, или вне функции. Если составной литерал объявлен вне функции, то он имеет статистическую длительность хранения, а иначе автоматическую длительность хранения.

Данная запись

```
int *a = (int[]){10, 20, 30};
```

эквивалентна

```
int arr[] = {10,20,30};
int *a = arr;
```

Comment: То есть если во втором варианте мы через указатель будем менять элементы то эти изменения коснутся именованного массива. Значит в составном литерале неименованный массив также будет изменен если будут изменения через указатель. Я правильно понимаю?!

Comment: @MaximPro Да, вы правильно понимаете. Вы это можете сами проверить.

Comment: Проверить наврятли ибо как я могу посмотреть неименованый массив кроме как через указатель на него =)(Хотя если брать утверждение что на этот массив мы ссылаемся указателем то все ок)
Кстати по скорости эти конструкции равнозначны?

Comment: @MaximPro Да что вас так волнует мифическая скорость? Эта скорость вообще не зависит от конструкций.

Comment: Просто интересно узнать не более :)